# Progress bar not rounded on right side when complete

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I was looking at my badge progress and saw this UI issue with the progress bar of one of the badges.

[image: progress bar] [image]

The right side does not have rounded corners like the left. I assume this is a `border-radius` issue of some sort. Looks awkward.

Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit). Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34).

*I cannot speak to the validity of this issue on other sites because I could not reproduce the same situation.*

Comment: How are you seeing a completed badge that still has the numbers (5/5) there?

Comment: @BSMP there's another conditional for that badge: 
positive question record

Comment: yep `overflow:hidden` is missing on the parent bar.